# C# Lambda Builder Pattern

Tags: c#, lambda, builder

I have a class and it has 11 properties (most are inherited). I don't quite like passing in 11 parameters. I know I could create a `ModelBuilder` class and do the following:

`new ModelBuilder().WithProp1(prop1).WithProp2(prop2).Build();`

But I was thinking of only one method generic enough to accept a `Func` which you can then specify the prop to assign:

```
public Car With<TOut>(Func<Car, TOut> lambda)
{
    lambda.Invoke(this);
    return this;
}
```

Usage:

```
var car = new Car()
        .With(x => x.VehicleType = "Sedan")
        .With(x => x.Wheels = 4)
        .With(x => x.Colour = "Pink")
        .With(x => x.Model = "fancyModelName")
        .With(x => x.Year = "2007")
        .With(x => x.Engine = "Large")
        .With(x => x.WeightKg = 2105)
        .With(x => x.InvoiceNumber = "1234564")
        .With(x => x.ServicePlanActive = true)
        .With(x => x.PassedQA = false)
        .With(x => x.Vin = "blabla");
```

This seems to work. My question: is there anything I'm missing here in terms of implementation (barring the obvious - dragging this method to an interface or helper class)? Are there any gotchas that may surface with this implementation that I am overlooking?

Comment: And how is it better than `var car = new Car {Wheels = 4, ...}`?

Comment: @Evk: My guess would be that the OP wasn't aware of that option. If that is the case then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers

Comment: Seems like all you need is a `Action<Car>`, but as already stated an object initializer would make more sense here.

Comment: This is exactly what the class initialisation syntax is for (mentioned above); you should use it. Don't try to over-engineer this if all you need to do is create a class.

Comment: So instead of invoking a single constructor you invoke a constructor and 11 methods with 11 lambdas? Who mentioned performance?

Comment: What do you mean that this works? It doesn't work at all. Calling `lambda.Invoke(this);` just throws away the return value - it doesn't set anything.

Comment: @Enigmativity but OP doesn't care about return value. Of course he should be using Action then, but still Func also "works".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're over complicating things, instead, you should leverage the object initializer syntax which is much simpler and more readable.

```
var car = new Car { 
     VehicleType = "Sedan", 
     Wheels = 4,
     Colour = "Pink", 
     ... 
};
```

Answer (score 7):

If you like to stick to something like your original approach, I suggest the following, which simplifies it:

```
public static T With<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
{
     action(obj);
     return obj;
}
```

This extension method lets you initialize the properties of your object in a cleaner way:

```
var car = new Car().With(c =>
{
    c.VehicleType = "Sedan";
    c.Model = "fancyModelName";
    //and so on
});
```